# How to make navbar not changing width after fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that looks like this:

[image: wrong sample]

but when i added `position: fixed` on the header, the width changed and become like this:

[image]

Here is my `index.html`

```
    <header>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/rocket-logo-png-4.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <h4>Rockode</h4>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="nav-link active"><a href="#">Beranda</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Produk</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Pengembang</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Kontak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="header-right">
            <button class="btn btn-sign-up">Daftar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sign-in">Masuk</button>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <article>This is article</article>
            <article></article>
        </div>
        <aside></aside>
    </main>
```

and here is `style.css`

```
main {
    background-color: white;
    height: 720px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 188px;
  }

header {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    height: 88px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the problem is, but I just added this and it works fine...

```
main {
position: relative;
padding-top: 88px
}

header {
position: fixed;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ktxzfvL/

Comment: actually i had 2 questions and bad in explain it, sorry for that.

And your answer solved my first problem, so i try to edit the question. Thanks!

After added `position: fixed` on the header, the header width getting smaller and looks like the image on my question section.

Comment: PS: I've add the width on header. my bad didn't see it before. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

That was my bad for didn't notice the `width` value on header section.

It solved by declaring `width: 100%`.